# How to make Pattern and alert for the following

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink

I've this code which gives locationID and temp, I want a pattern that spits alert whenever the temp > THRESHOLD_TEMPERATURE

I've Tried :-

```
        val pattern1: Pattern[Event,_] = Pattern.begin[Event]("first")
          .subtype(Event.getClass)
          .where( (evt -> evt.getTemp()) >= TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD)
          .within(Time.seconds(5))

        val patternStream: PatternStream[Event] = CEP.pattern(f,pattern1)
       val alerts: DataStream[String] = patternStream.flatSelect(
          (in: Map[String,String], out: Collector[String]) => {
            var first: String = in.get("first")
            if (first >= TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD){

               out.collect("Temperature above danger zone")
           }
          }
        )
```

This is the code for which alert is to be made :-

```
case class Event(locationID: String, temp: Double)

    val TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD: Double = 50.00

    val see: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")


    val src = see.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[ObjectNode]("broadcast",
      new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties))


    var ask = src.map{
      r => r.get("value")
      }


    var data = ask.map { v => {
      val loc = v.get("locationID").asInstanceOf[String]
      val temperature = v.get("temp").asDouble()

      (loc, temperature)
    }}
//    data.print()

    var f = data.keyBy(
        v => v._2
      )

    f.print()
    see.execute()
```

pattern is getting overloaded, also flatSelect

Answer (score 0):

CEP is for detecting Patterns in sequences of events, which doesn't really fit this particular problem. Finding events where the temp > THRESHOLD doesn't require pattern matching -- a simple filter or flatmap will do the job. E.g., you could have a flatmap that transforms every event where the temp is too high to an alert, and ignores all other events.

As for your CEP-based solution, I don't understand what you are saying is going wrong with it. But a couple of things look wrong. The `within` clause won't do anything: since your patterns are only one event long, they don't have any duration. And you are keying the stream by the temperature, which seems odd.